# How to apply CSS positioning to a specific point on an SVG path

Tags: css, animation, svg, path

So i'm looking at some experimenting with backgrounds and SVG's, and would like to have a large (Attached) triangle pointing to the left. I would like to keep point 1 fixed to it's position, while allowing the other two back points of the triangle to stretch with the page as one drags it wider to the right. So in my mind this would mean having point 1 as a fixed position, and points 2 and 3 as relatively positioned, but I don't if it's possible to apply CSS to specific points within a path.[image: Illustration]

I'm open to any ways of addressing this matter.

Thanks!

Comment: "I don't if it's possible to apply CSS to specific points within a path"...no it's not. It's not an element (he point) so it's not selectable by CSS (*at the moment*)

Comment: Frankly, if the SVG ***scaling*** is set up right you can do this with normal bg image properties I would expect..

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the path coordinates with CSS, but you can control the SVG element size and position.

All you need to do is set the SVG to `preserveAspectRatio="none"` so that its contents stretch to fit the container it is in.

```css
div
{
  padding-left: 200px;
}

svg
{
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,50 100,0 100,100 Z" fill="#7be"/>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul LeBeau, this will definitely suffice what I wanting to achieve. 

Much appreciated!